# Android Developer Tools Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, 14.04, eclipse, adt

I recently updated my computer to Ubuntu 14.04, and I really liked and enjoyed all new features, however within an hour or two, my enjoyment ended. I soon learned that the ADT bundle would crash unexpectedly and all of the time. It doesn't say it crashed. It just randomly exits and then I'm left set back a couple of minutes, which is very inconvenient when coding android apps. Especially given the fact that it 'crashes' after only using it for a couple of minutes.

Is this a common problem? Is this unheard of? Is there a known solution for this?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

---

EDIT

I decided to run ADT from the terminal to see what output was there when it 'crashes' and so here it is.

No bp log location saved, using default.

```
[000:000] Cpu: 6.23.10, x2, 2668Mhz, 1968MB

[000:000] Computer model: Not available

[000:000] Browser XEmbed support present: 1

[000:000] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.

[000:000] Using Gtk2 toolkit

No bp log location saved, using default.

[000:000] Cpu: 6.23.10, x2, 2668Mhz, 1968MB

[000:000] Computer model: Not available

[000:397] No bp log location saved, using default.

[000:397] Cpu: 6.23.10, x2, 2668Mhz, 1968MB

[000:397] Computer model: Not available

[000:397] Browser XEmbed support present: 1

[000:397] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.

[000:397] Using Gtk2 toolkit

[000:334] No bp log location saved, using default.

[000:334] Cpu: 6.23.10, x2, 2668Mhz, 1968MB

[000:334] Computer model: Not available

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

-

So I need a bp log? I don't know that is. Hope this bit helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same thing, but an update fixed it for me. Just doing a regular update check says you are up to date, you need to do it through add new software. Read this

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513524/error-message-this-android-sdk-requires-android-developer-toolkit-version-22-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513524/error-message-this-android-sdk-requires-android-developer-toolkit-version-22-6/)

It sorted me out fine.

Comment: For me, ADT crashes on 14.04 as soon as I hover over a keyword or something. It seems related to displaying the little help box that usually comes up. The above answer did not solve this for me.

Comment: @foh1981 yes that is exactly what was happening to me, but updating actually worked great for me.